# Can a group of nodes be saved?

Tags: node-editor

If I have a material that needs to have a dozen nodes or so attached to it and I hit + in the materials panel the material duplicates but not the nodes.

Is there a way to migrate nodes and their connections from one material to another?

Answer (score 1):

Use shift-right-click to multi-select nodes, or <kbd>B</kbd> to border-select a group of nodes and their connections.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (or platform equivalent) will copy and paste nodes across materials.

**NOTE:** After pasting some nodes, try moving the nodes around with the mouse.  Blender has a bad habit of pasting node copies *exactly* on top of existing nodes, and it becomes almost impossible to see that anything has changed.  Slide the new nodes away to reveal old nodes underneath.

Also, consider using [Node Groups](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/nodes/groups.html) to avoid having a bunch of duplicated nodes. This way, you can fix problems in a complex node structure and have the fixes apply to multiple materials at once.

A node group can have inputs for customizing in different ways, to make nodes more re-usable in different materials.  You can create a node group just by multi-selecting the nodes and picking *Make group* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. Then, get in and out of the node group editor with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Finally, you can add references to your node group from other materials, with *Add -> Group -> {GroupName}*.

Comment: I tired Ctrl-C and put the mouse over on the node panel and did Ctrl-V but nothing happened. That is why I asked.

Comment: Try moving the existing nodes after pasting.  The new copies will be *exactly* on top of old copies, and you may not realize that anything has happened.

Comment: I mean I duplicate a material with no nodes and paste and nothing happens.

Comment: Oh.  Turn on "use nodes" before you paste.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question right but I think this is what your looking for.

[image]

You can also use node groups like this.

[image]

Comment: The paste material was exactly what I was looking for.