# Do I have to repeat node editing to import a texture that has 5 types of images?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a texture ZIP file from a (probably) famous texture web site, and it had five files like so:

[image]

I followed a tutorial video to apply that texture to a face, but it was not just selecting the downloaded file. As you see, it was quite a lot of input. But isn't this process the same for all future textures (apart from minor adjustments in the `Strength` parameters)? If it is the same, can't it be done at once, instead of repeating this process over and over again for each texture?

[image]

Comment: Create a node group and save it as part of the default file (read: [how to save a node setup for easy access in default scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145716) and [can a group of nodes be saved](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66838/can-a-group-of-nodes-be-saved) and [why are node groups not being saved in my startup file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77046/why-are-node-groups-not-being-saved-in-my-startup-file))

Comment: Well, if you're using textures from Poliigon, there is the [Poliigon Material converter addon](https://help.poliigon.com/en/articles/2540839-poliigon-material-converter-addon-for-blender) which does exactly that. Plus it connects the textures into correct inputs for you.

Comment: Hello :). If you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. Thanks a lot.